# How to run the app with spring-cloud-starter-aws locally?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I need to run Spring Boot based app locally. It uses spring-cloud-starter-aws dependency.
The problem is that it tries to connect to EC2 metadata service always. Setting "cloud.aws.*" properties doesn't help.
I expect that default AWS credentials chain will be used, credentials and region will be read from one of AWS preferred way (e.g. ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials files).
I tried to set cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain property but spring-cloud-starter-aws doesn't care

I found [examples](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp) that use CloudFormation stack for very strange reason to run the app locally.

When I use AWS SDK for Java default AWS chain is used without any issues - I don't need to do anything specific for local running of the application (locally it reads credentials from files and on EC2 it uses instance metadata service). But with Spring Boot it doesn't work out of the box and I need to enable local running somehow.

I use 2.2.2.RELEASE version of Spring Boot and 2.2.1.RELEASE version of Spring Cloud. I have a feeling they introduced regression, because in previous versions it worked without problems.

Any ideas how to run the app locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following lines to configuration helps:

```
cloud.aws.region.static=my region
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.metrics.CloudWatchExportAutoConfiguration
```

So Spring uses AWS default chain but only for credentials. AWS SDK uses it for region and other configuration parameters too. **So this is Spring bug for sure**.
It still gives a warning about no connection to instance metadata service once during application start but more or less this solution can be used for local running.

If we don't have the last line with excluding CloudWatchExportAutoConfiguration, there will be many exceptions in stack trace while closing the app. I use CloudWatch metrics in my app.

I guess rationale behind excluding aws auto configuration is that it has conflicts with boot actuator but I'm not sure.

Comment: I followed these steps, but I am still facing the same issue that it is trying to connect EC2 instance metadata URL. is there anyother solution you have ?

Comment: cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      auto: false
      static: us-east-1

Comment: @AmitAgarwal - set the following environment variable `AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED=true` and the following spring properties:  `cloud.aws.region.auto=false`, `cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1`

You'll still see an exception on startup: `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: EC2 Instance Metadata Service is disabled`, but it will not attempt to fetch metadata.  If you leave out the environment variable, it will still attempt to connect to the metadata endpoint, but will timeout and fall back to the static values.